# Azure function set maximum concurrency

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to set the maximum number of concurrently running function instances when using the consumption plan. I'm aware that I can set some max numbers in the host.json - but that is for a single function instance. So even when I set

```
{
  "queues": {
    "batchSize": 1,    
    "newBatchThreshold": 1
  }
}
```

It just starts to scale out to multiple instances. This would be perfect if the my backend could handle the load, but in my case it can't so I would like function app to have a max number of parallelism set, e.g. max 5 instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible at present, though feel free to file an issue on [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues).

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234413/limiting-the-number-of-concurrent-jobs-on-azure-functions-queue) for other discussion on concurrency, your only option from a functions perspective is to switch to dedicated.

Comment: That is pretty sad. Guess I have to open an issue then.